# Trying to make an array to hold values for a validation list

Tags: excel, vba

Unable to use an array variable for data validation (Drop down list).

Also:

1. The immediate window doesn't show the value for `MyArray` when the line for debug.print is being executed.
2. Nothing happens when the line `Range("A" & r).value = MyArray(r)` is executed. The excel sheet is still blank.

   ```
   Sub Testing()

       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Dim MyArray() As String
       Dim r As Integer
       Dim WsCount As Integer

       r = 1

       WsCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
       ReDim MyArray(1 To WsCount)

       For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
           MyArray(r) = ws.Name
           r = r + 1
           If r <= 12 Then
               Debug.Print MyArray(r)
               Range("A" & r).Value = MyArray(r)
           End If
       Next ws

       ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Validation.Add _
       Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=MyArray

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Oh I work that out. Misplaced the `r = r + 1`. It should been below the debug and range line.

Comment: But the data validation portion still isn't working

Comment: You found out yourself while I was answering :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your 2nd question first:
Actually, the code does execute, however what you are doing is:

1. Fill cell at index `r`.
2. Increase index `r` (which now points to an empty cell of your array)
3. Write the empty string to your range

Now about the validation. `Formula1` expects comma-delimited values (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.add)) aka a string, not an array.

You can easily correct that line of code this way (I removed the Operator which I think is unneeded).

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Validation.Add _
 Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
          Formula1:=WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, MyArray)
```